# grep dates in a text file to less than 30 days old and move to a new file

Tags: grep, date

A script that should look out for texts with a date inside the file thats 30 days older than the current date then move to another file like the
$ awk '$NF <= "2018-05-01"' ip.txt
but need a command to get text with dates 30 days older than the system current date automatically without having to manually change the script everyday

Comment: A script that should look out for texts with a date inside the file thats 30 days older than the current date then move to another file like the $ awk '$NF <= "2018-05-01"' ip.txt but need a command to get text with dates 30 days older than the system current date automatically without having to manually change the script everyday

Answer (score 0):

cmd:

```
for i in {1..30}; do date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$i day ago"; done >outputfile
```

output:

```
 cat outputfile
2018-12-17
2018-12-16
2018-12-15
2018-12-14
2018-12-13
2018-12-12
2018-12-11
2018-12-10
2018-12-09
2018-12-08
2018-12-07
2018-12-06
2018-12-05
2018-12-04
2018-12-03
2018-12-02
2018-12-01
2018-11-30
2018-11-29
2018-11-28
2018-11-27
2018-11-26
2018-11-25
2018-11-24
2018-11-23
2018-11-22
2018-11-21
2018-11-20
2018-11-19
2018-11-18
```

Comment: $ cat ip.txt 
Blah blah blah 2018-12-13
Blah blah blah 2018-02-13
Blah blah blah 2018-05-01

$ awk '$NF < "2018-05-01"' ip.txt 
Blah blah blah 2018-02-13
if possible similar to that without having to manually input the current date as shown in the 2018-05-01 but automatically system date